# IPhone - Removing the 'currentLocation' blue dot from an MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I'm trying to replace the blue 'currentLocation' dot with a custom annotation. That code is working well (I am just implementing viewForAnnotation and cycling through that, replacing the annotation ofClass MKUserLocation with a custom image).

However, once I replace the annotation, the user's current location stops updating. All related functions (like didUpdateUserLocation) thus stop being called. This causes a lot of problems. I tried implementing the various code blocks at [MKUserLocation Custom View not moving!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769363/mkuserlocation-custom-view-not-moving) but I couldn't get it to work. After extensive Googling and stackoverflow searching, I've come up with nothing.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Here is the code for the viewForAnnotation method:

_userDot is an instance variable within MapScreen.m (the place where all of this code is). It's alloced in the viewDidLoad and is of type MKAnnotationView. Basically I couldn't just get rid of the annotation, so I wanted to set it to an invisible image instead (currently 1x1 for debugging).

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)newMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        //Initialize a new MKAnnotationView using the current userLocation annotation
        //Then make it invisible (because we are cheap like that)
        //TODO: Make it actually invisible (right now it is 1x1 for debugging)
        if (_userDot)
        {
            _userDot.annotation = annotation;
            _userDot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mister_taco"];
            _userDot.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1);
            return _userDot;
        }
        else
            return nil;
    }
    else {*/
        return nil;
    //}
}
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Please post your code for custom annotation. i implemented it successfully in my project. I might be able to help you after looking at your code.

Comment: added the code. sorry about that.

Comment: ok..i will see and reply